# Is it possible to install ruby-2.6.5 in ubuntu 22.04 via rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, ubuntu-22.04

I have ubuntu 22.04 version and I am trying to install ruby-2.6.5 via rvm .

I am getting below error

```
rails-@rails-Lenovo-V15-G3-IAP:~/Desktop/Demo_Project/JobFusion$ rvm install ruby-2.6.5
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /home/rails-/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/bin is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby-3.1.2
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
ruby-2.6.5 - #removing src/ruby-2.6.5.............................................................................................................................................................................-
Error running '__rvm_rm_rf /home/rails-/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.5',
please read /home/rails-/.rvm/log/1699524961_ruby-2.6.5/remove.src.log
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/22.04/x86_64/ruby-2.6.5.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/rails-/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.6.5 - #downloading ruby-2.6.5, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.6.5 - #already extracted to /home/rails-/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.5
ruby-2.6.5 - #configuring.
Error running './configure --prefix=/home/rails-/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
please read /home/rails-/.rvm/log/1699524961_ruby-2.6.5/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
rails-@rails-Lenovo-V15-G3-IAP:~/Desktop/Demo_Project/JobFusion$
```

[image: screenshot rvm install output]

So I wanted to know whether is it even possible to have ruby-2.6.5 in ubuntu versions greater than 20?

Comment: Did you check the "execute commands as login shell" setting in your terminal settings (commonly found under "profile")? Then restart the terminal after changing the setting.

Comment: I am newbie, I dont know what you are saying. Could you please explain more?